# Weird Table Output When Using Alias and Case Statement on Khan Academy's Challenge

Tags: sql, case

I'm fairly new to SQL and I taught myself to SQL on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql#sql-basics). I create a database table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Data_Exp (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Subject TEXT, 
                       Label TEXT, Gender TEXT, X1 INTEGER, X2 INTEGER, 
                       X3 INTEGER, X4 INTEGER, X5 INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Data_Exp(Subject, Label, Gender, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) VALUES("S01", "A", "F", 5, 7, 6, 5, 4);
INSERT INTO Data_Exp(Subject, Label, Gender, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) VALUES("S02", "B", "M", 8, 8, 6, 4, 6);
INSERT INTO Data_Exp(Subject, Label, Gender, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) VALUES("S03", "A", "M", 6, 1, 4, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO Data_Exp(Subject, Label, Gender, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) VALUES("S04", "C", "F", 3, 3, 7, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO Data_Exp(Subject, Label, Gender, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) VALUES("S05", "B", "F", 9, 2, 5, 3, 7);
```

The output of above code is:

[image]

Then I continue by adding this code:

```
SELECT Subject, Gender, Label, ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1) AS Y FROM Data_Exp;
```

and get the following result (as expected):

[image]

Then I use CASE statement to evaluate column **Level**:

```
SELECT Subject, Gender, Label, (SELECT CASE WHEN Y > 6 THEN "Level 6"
    WHEN Y > 5 THEN "Level 5" 
    WHEN Y > 4 THEN "Level 4"
    WHEN Y > 3 THEN "Level 3"
    WHEN Y > 2 THEN "Level 2"
    WHEN Y > 1 THEN "Level 1"
    END AS "Level" FROM (SELECT ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1) AS Y FROM Data_Exp)) AS Level FROM Data_Exp;
```

but instead of getting this result:

[image]

I got this weird output in column **Level**

[image]

Where did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your query will not work as you are doing some sort of cartesian join

What you are looking is something like the solution below

```
 SELECT Subject, 
 Gender, 
 Label, 
CASE WHEN ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1)  > 6 THEN "Level 6"
     WHEN ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1)  > 5 THEN "Level 5" 
     WHEN ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1)  > 4 THEN "Level 4"
     WHEN ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1)  > 3 THEN "Level 3"
     WHEN ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1)  > 2 THEN "Level 2"
     WHEN ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1)  > 1 THEN "Level 1"
     END AS "Level" 
  FROM Data_Exp;
```

Otherwise you can use the template below.

The query below will need tinkering and is probably tedious for what you are trying to achieve

```
SELECT Subject, 
Gender, 
Label, 
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN Y > 6 THEN "Level 6"
    WHEN Y > 5 THEN "Level 5" 
    WHEN Y > 4 THEN "Level 4"
    WHEN Y > 3 THEN "Level 3"
    WHEN Y > 2 THEN "Level 2"
    WHEN Y > 1 THEN "Level 1"
    END AS "Level" 
 FROM 
 (SELECT ROUND(0.4*X1 + 0.15*(X2+X3+X4+X5),1) AS "Y" FROM Data_Exp) AS "lol"
INNER JOIN Data_Exp ON  Data_Exp.Gender = lol.Gender AND Data_Exp.Label = lol.Label
) AS "Level" 
FROM
 FROM Data_Exp;
```

Last but not least, knowing your database (`Postgres` , `MySql` or else) will help as there are other solutions like declarative variables you can use to store your formula and that are definitely easier.